# Ajax POST request to Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, post

I am new to Flask and JavaScript and wanted to create a simple web application. It is almost done, but I just need to complete the last functionality. I use a stopwatch written in JavaScript and after clicking a button (it is nested inside a form, but I want to pass the variable from JavaScript (that creates this stopwatch and return time) to Flask via JSON.

For now I tried the following:

```
function charge_time(btn_id)
{
    clearInterval(state.interval);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/timer/",
        data: { time : state.time, id: btn_id },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
        }
      });
    state.time = 0;
    stopwatch.classList.replace("active", "inactive");
}
```

I call this function after clicking this button:

```
<td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="{{ task.task_id }}" onclick="charge_time(this.id)"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></button>
</td>
```

So I also pass the id of an button as an argument that is a unique task id, because this data is represented as a table and I need to know for which task the time needs to be updated.

Here is my Flask route function:

```
@app.route('/timer/', methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def timer():
    """ Handle saving timer"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        time = request.get_data()
        print(time, file=sys.stderr)
        task_id = request.form['task_id']
        if not time:
            return render_template("error_handling.html", message="Could not charge time")
        db.execute("UPDATE tasks SET charge = ? WHERE task_id = ? AND user_id = ?", time, task_id,session["user_id"])
        return redirect('/')
```

The result is that I get the 400 Bad request and the print function returns something like this: "b'time=3&id=9". I was looking for a way to send JSON in a different way, or pass two variables (as this would give be two variables, task_id and time, but other errors occurred).

How can I get this right? Most of the answers are related to using Ajax as with a form from the HTML side, but I cannot nest them, because one is taking the whole table for another purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the POST method, instead of using query parameters, you should get the data via URL parameters like this:

```
@app.route('/timer/<time>/<id>', methods=["POST"])
def timer(time, id):
    # Use time and id here
```